# Sending single request to call different systems in WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, aggregate, esb

Hi I have a scenario in which I need to send just one request (can be a proxy url) which can call multiple endpoints and return the response after aggreating all of them.

Currently I am using a proxy service implementation to achieve it but is returns just one response(can be from any of the endpoints) and not able to combine responses from other systems/endpoints. Though I can the response from another endpoint in my server console.

Below is the code I implemented so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="RLProxy"
       transports="http,https"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <clone>
            <target>
               <sequence>
                  <property name="Authorization"
                            value="Basic username:password"
                            scope="transport"/>
                  <property name="messageType"
                            value="application/json"
                            scope="axis2"
                            type="STRING"/>
                  <send>
                     <endpoint>
                        <address uri="http://localhost:7070/adap/cn=AlkaA,ou=People,dc=maxcrc,dc=com"/>
                     </endpoint>
                  </send>
               </sequence>
            </target>
            <target>
               <sequence>
                  <property name="Authorization"
                            value="Basic username:password"
                            scope="transport"/>
                  <property name="messageType"
                            value="application/json"
                            scope="axis2"
                            type="STRING"/>
                  <send>
                     <endpoint>
                        <address uri="http://localhost:7070/adap/cn=AlkaV,ou=People,dc=maxcrc,dc=com"/>
                     </endpoint>
                  </send>
               </sequence>
            </target>
         </clone>
         <aggregate>
            <completeCondition>
               <messageCount min="3"/>
            </completeCondition>
            <onComplete expression="$body/jsonObject">
               <send/>
            </onComplete>
         </aggregate>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

I am guessing there is some issue with aggregate expression. I don't know how is works. Please help me. If there is some other issue please let me know how to fix it.Right now I am testing just one scenario with the same system endpoints having different search for LDAP but I need to implement it for different kinds of systems. In am stuck with it for many days.
Please help.

Comment: My requirement is similar to the one mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755003/wso2-esb-construct-one-message-from-multiple-web-service-calls/37762798?noredirect=1#comment62994325_37762798 but I already have my APIs ready for different applications.

Answer (score 1):

You have placed the aggregate mediator inside the inSequence. But, it has to be placed in the outSequence. Thats the place the responses from the backend requests arrive.

Furthermore, if you are invoking just two endpoints, it doesn't look correct to have the minimum message count to wait before aggregation to 3.

Refere the following documentation and samples for aggregate mediator.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Aggregate+Mediator

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Sample+400%3A+Message+Splitting+and+Aggregating+the+Responses

Comment: If you got this working, please mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: I even tried using aggregate in outsequence but I get the following error on console:(Both responses are coming)
Direction: response, Payload: [{"id":"8a0e0153
cdcbe6230468","email":"Kevin.ollo@comyb.com","name":"900070","lastname":"Mo
llo","displayableName":"9000070","firstname":"Kevin"}]
Direction: response, Payload: [{"id":"8a0f800ee","email":"","name":"spadmin","lastname":"Administrator","displayableName":"The Administrator","firstname":"The"}]
AggregateMediator Error evaluating expression:$body/jsonObject
Could not find matching elements to aggregate.

Comment: This is because the onComplete expression I think. You are getting a json response from the two backends. Therefore try json-eval method in the expression as mentioned in the following doc.https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB480/JSON+Support#JSONSupport-AccessingcontentfromJSONpayloads